# File version control vs revision control

Tags: git, svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

I used SVN + GIT but still find it's not quite satisfied as they do not use file-level version control. Anybody can tell me why all types of version controls software out there does not support tracking version for invidual files ?

Basically what i wanted to do is develop small libraries on their own branch then continuously integrated into the master branch. The problem is each branch not only contains those files but also the project settings files, the configuration, the test scripts ... that i needed to put in version control while developing the library as well. And I wanted that the revision for each library will count separately. And when I create another branch from master, I will always have up to dated libraries that I can use. And if I do bugfixes on that branch I will be able to push back the modified library files only to the master branch, then on master, I will be able to push the bugfixed onto the correct library branch, too.

So in summary the problem is how can I merge only selected files into arbitrary branches and tracking the changes for each file separately ?

Is it a way to do that or am I doing something that terribly wrong here ? I'm getting confused. Please help !

Comment: `git submodule` can cover what you've described.  However, it might not be so useful to you because you're using `svn` + `git` as opposed to simply `git`.

Comment: by svn + git I mean i've tried svn then git, still not found what i really want to do. For example I have to develop a library A and a library B that depends on library A. So in library B i will need to add A as a submodule, but submodule means the whole A repository will be put inside B where I only need the compiled version of A (say a A.dll or something into B). Then when A has changed, I can easily pick up the changes by update submodule right inside B. Are there a way to do that ? Pick 1 folder or 1 file instead of the whole repository and use as submodule ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use submodules and not bother with SVN. You will be able to mix and match as you please.